# Random Bug in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been working on a project for the GMTK 2022 Game Jam recently, and I ran into a very strange problem. I have a dash that starts when you are moving and press space. It moves you in the direction of your velocity, then for a short time lets you move very quickly. It works perfectly fine in all cases, unless the direction you are moving is up and to the left, in which case, the if statement strangely won't trigger. I'm sure this is something idiotic, but I've been troubleshooting it for the last hour and it's been driving me insane.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    playerInputh = 0;
    playerInputv = 0;
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        playerInputh = 1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        playerInputh = -1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("right") && Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        playerInputh = 0;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        playerInputv = 1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
    {
        playerInputv = -1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("up") && Input.GetKey("down"))
    {
        playerInputv = 0;
    }

    Vector2 screenPosition = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
    Vector2 mouseWorldPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPosition);


    //This is the dash that isn't working:
    if ((Input.GetKeyDown(/*"right shift"*/"space")) && (playerInputh != 0 || playerInputv != 0))
    {
        Debug.Log("Dash");
        //Vector2 transform2dposition = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        m_Rigidbody.AddForce((m_Rigidbody.velocity) * 500f);
        wJumpTimer = airControlAfterJump;
        speed = maxSpeed*3.5f;
        StartCoroutine(Roll());
    }


}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //no moving while jumping!!!
    if (wJumpTimer > 0)
    {
        wJumpTimer -= 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wJumpTimer = 0;
    }

    //move
    if (playerInputh != 0 && playerInputv != 0) //make diagonals no super sayan
    {
        playerInputh *= moveLimiter;
        playerInputv *= moveLimiter;

        one_h = playerInputh;//futureproof
        one_v = playerInputv;
    }
    if ((playerInputh != 0 || playerInputv != 0) && speed < maxSpeed) //are we hitting the move buttons??
    {
        speed += acceleration;//accelerate
        one_h = playerInputh;//futureproof
        one_v = playerInputv;

    }
    else
    {     
        if (speed > 0f) //are we getting off the ride
        {
            speed -= deceleration; //decelerate
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 0f; //no funny buisness
        }
    }

    m_Rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(one_h * speed, one_v * speed); //actually move





}


void SetFace(int diceNumb)
{
    rndr.sprite = sprites[diceNumb];
}
IEnumerator Roll()
{
    Random diceNumb = new Random();
    rndr.sprite = sprites[diceNumb.Next(0,5)];
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    rndr.sprite = sprites[diceNumb.Next(0, 5)];
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    rndr.sprite = sprites[diceNumb.Next(0, 5)];
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    rndr.sprite = sprites[diceNumb.Next(0, 5)];
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.125f);
    var newValue = diceNumb.Next(0, 5);
    FaceValue = newValue + 1;
    rndr.sprite = sprites[newValue];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are your inputs setup? I am suspecting you have one key bound to multiple actions, like one key is set up as primary for an action and alternate for another action.

Personally I'd also stop using the assignment operators and increment instead. Instead of

```
    playerInputh = 0;
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        playerInputh = 1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        playerInputh = -1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("right") && Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        playerInputh = 0;
    }
```

you can do

```
    playerInputv = 0;
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        playerInputh += 1;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        playerInputh += -1;
    }
```

Net result is the same here - if you push both keys the result sums to zero, but the code is easier to read (IMO).

When you check things for key bindings also check alternates for space, because that's another one of the triggers you need to dash.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! If you want it, here's the code for the movement, I will warn you it's a bit scuffed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code still isn't working, and for whatever reason whilst moving up and right you can't dash